# geocoder updates with improper location

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, clgeocoder

I am working on the ios application where I have to type the place name and based on the text the location is found out using below mention function, but,I am not getting the proper location.My actual location should be

```
latitude = 15.494248  
longitude= 73.817682
```

while I am getting

```
latitude = 40.015038  
longitude = -75.239108
```

So to avoid irregularities I am thinking to use Google IOS map but I am not getting any proper
function to find out the location.

So is there any function which will give me accurate location and that too using Google maps

```
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:sender.text completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)

{
    if (error) 
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    } 
    else 
    {
        thePlacemark = [placemarks lastObject];
        float spanX = 1.00725;
        float spanY = 1.00725;

        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center.latitude = thePlacemark.location.coordinate.latitude;
        region.center.longitude = thePlacemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
        region.span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY);

        NSLog(@"%f", region.center.latitude);
        NSLog(@"%f", region.center.longitude);

        [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
        [self addAnnotation:thePlacemark];
    }
}];
```

Comment: What's the exact value of sender.text that you're submitting?

Comment: Unfortunately, that place is spelled "Achedemy" in Apple Maps and even more unfortunately, CLGeocoder doesn't seem to use a "sounds like" algorithm here.  If you want to try Google instead, there is plenty of info available on it [starting here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#geocoding).

Comment: @Anna. Thanks.But how did you found name spelled in Apple Maps

Comment: I entered the coordinates 15.494248, 73.817682 into Apple Maps and that's the title of the pin it placed there.